# CraftBukkit ignoring eula.txt

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-bukkit

Literally what the title is. I have `EULA=TRUE` in `eula.txt`, and the server is not seeing that. I have no clue how to fix it.

Comment: Noteworthy is ALL MC servers do that on my machine

Comment: The .exe works, though. How strange...

Comment: If starting Bukkit from the terminal, make sure that your working directory is in the server folder. I didn't do that and it tried creating a server in my home folder. Do this with the command cd path\to\folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a shortcut to the jar, then, edit its properties. In the target field, I put `"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -jar` right before the location of the .jar. Ran the shortcut and it worked!

Comment: If that fixes it, you set up your server wrong. [Read this!](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Setting_up_a_server)